# Type error with model method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to add a shortcut method to simplify output of a my data. I have written the following code (unnecessary bits redacted):

```
address_line_one = models.CharField(max_length=100)
address_line_two = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
address_city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
address_state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
address_zip = models.IntegerField()

def address(self):
    return self.address_line_one+" "+self.address_line_two+" "+self.address_city+" "+self.address_state+" "+self.address_zip
```

This is rather... simple. When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/srv/www/energy/energy/customers/models.py", line 83, in address
    return self.address_line_two+" "+self.address_city+" "+self.address_state+" "+self.address_zip
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: If address_zip is an integer shouldn't you convert it to a string when concatenating it? str(self.address_zip)

Comment: True, but not the source of my issue (i tried removing the zip before)

Comment: Out of curiosity, I decided to try "return 'test'", and I am still getting that error. I think I am missing some syntax needed for methods or something

Comment: Figured it out - apparently it was an issue with how I was using the shell to test

Answer (score 1):

Python is strongly typed. That means you can't concatenate an int to a string, without explicitly converting it.

Luckily, there's a couple of shortcuts that will do the conversions, as well as making your code easier to read.

Firstly, any time you find yourself concatenating variables to string literals, you should be using string formatting:

```
return "%s %s %s %s %s" % (self.address_line_one,
                           self.address_line_two,
                           self.address_city,
                           self.address_state
                           self.address_zip)
```

You could also use the string `join` method, but for that you'll need to convert the zip integer explicitly:

```
return " ".join([self.address_line_one,
                 self.address_line_two,
                 self.address_city
                 self.address_state
                 unicode(self.address_zip)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough & well written answer. Unfortunately, it seems like no matter what I have on the return line, I get an error. Is there some django syntax I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def address(self):
    return " ".join([self.address_line_one, self.address_line_two, self.address_city, self.address_state, str(self.address_zip)])
```